# Nesting Forms for Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, Post, which has a many to many relationship with another model, Tag:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :section_id, :solved, :subject, :tag_ids, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :section
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comments
```

Here's Tag:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subject, :post_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

  validates(:subject, presence: true, :length => { minimum: 3, maximum: 15})
end
```

When I'm creating a Post, I need to allow the user to add Tags to the post at creation in the same form as the Title and Body of a Post. The tags are pre-created and will never be created within a post. I don't know how to do this. I want to use form_for so I can easily populate the fields of Post, but I don't know how to incorporate Tags into this and send it to the controller. Any suggestions? Here is what my controller is sending to the view:

```
@post = Post.new
@tags = Tag.all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need a field for user to input tags in the form, such as

```
<input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" />
```

when the request is posted to the controller, parsing the tags text,

```
tags = params["tags"].split(/\s+/) //assuming tags are separated by spaces
tags.each do |t|
  tag = Tag.find_or_create_by_name(t)
  your_post_object.tags << tag
end
```

and finally, don't forget to call `save` on `your_post_object`

Comment: I thought about this approach, but there are a few problems with it. First, the tags are pre-generated, so I need the users to select them with something like checkboxes. Second, I don't want to have two different forms on one page, so I need to submit this data with the main data I get for the Post object using form_for.

Comment: Take a close look at the form when asking a question here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). tags are pre-generated just means users cannot input tags doesn't exist in the database, which means you'll need to use ajax to get tags when users are typing. It's one form, not two forms. but you have to code it yourself, the relationship cannot be built through Post.new(params[:post])

Comment: cross this post today, maybe helpful for you. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/